# In C++, can an object share same polymorphic member with its base object?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory, constructor, polymorphism

I have the following problem that I really couldn't describe well within one sentense in the title.

I have a class hierarchy simplified to this that I cannot change

```
class Base {
  protected:
    std::vector<int> a_;

  public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    Base(std::vector<int> a): a_(std::move(a)) {}

    virtual void do_stuff() { /*modify a_*/ }  
};

class Derived: public Base {
  protected:
    std::vector<int> b_;

  public:
    Derived(std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b): Base(std::move(a)), b_(std::move(b)) {}

    void do_stuff() override {
      Base::do_stuff();
      /*modify b_*/
    }  
};
```

I need to add some functionality to this hierarchy, so I created an "extended" hierarchy:

```
class BaseExtended {
  private:    
    Base underlying_;
    int x_;

  public:
    virtual ~BaseExtended() = default;

    BeseExtended(std::vector<int> a, int x): underlying_(std::move(a)), x_(x) {}

    virtual void do_more() { 
      underlying_.do_stuff();
      /* do more stuff according to x_ */
    }
};

class DerivedExtended: public BaseExtended{
  private:    
    Derived underlying_;
    int y_;

  public:
    DerivedExtended(std::vector<int> a, int x, std::vector<int> b, int y)
     :BaseExtended(std::move(a), x), underlying_(std::move(b)), y_(y) {}

    void do_more() override {
      BaseExtended::do_more(); 
      underlying_.do_stuff();
      /* do more stuff according to y_ */
    }
};
```

But this didnt't do what I want, which is having *only* two vectors *v1* and *v2* stored after I call

```
std::shared_ptr<BaseExtended> de = new DerivedExtended(v1, 1, v2, 2);
```

I don't know if this can be achieved without modifing the original classes, especially how to store only one copy of vector *v1* in *DerivedExtended*. Could this be done?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<BaseExtended>(de)`

Comment: @curiousguy I gave the wrong example, I need to use it to down cast

Comment: @curiousguy Thank you, I have removed this misleading part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to dynamically allocate `underlying_` and have `BaseExtended` have a `protected` contructor for derived classes which takes a parameter of type `Base*` (or preferably a smart pointer) for `underlying_`.

Something like this:

```cpp
class BaseExtended {
...
protected:
  std::unique_ptr<Base> underlying_;

  BeseExtended(int x, std::unique_ptr<Base> underlying): underlying_(std::move(underlying)), x_(x) {}
...
};
class DerivedExtended: public BaseExtended {
...
public:
    DerivedExtended(std::vector<int> a, int x, std::vector<int> b, int y) : 
     :BaseExtended(std::make_unique<Derived>(std::move(a), std::move(b)), x), y_(y) {}
```

You then access `underlying_` though `BaseExtended` (since it is now `protected`).

This will prevent multiple versions of `a_` being created and it simplifies the code for the child somewhat, its a win win!

Do note that you have to be careful however, when calling `do_stuff()` on `underlying_` in `BaseExtended` you will probably want to qualify it will an explicit call to `Base::do_stuff()` (`underlying_->Base::do_suff()`) since otherwise if `Derived` overrides `do_stuff()` then it will be called twice by `DerivedExtended::do_more()` (and `Base::do_stuff()` will not be called).

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't fully understand your question at that point, but in any case, you just can't override data members, for a bunch of reasons.

The closest would be to set a owning const smart pointer to the "overridable" data "member", in the constructor, and to have protected constructors to let derived classes override the creation, and type, of the owned object.